# Why does it take that long for a timeline item to appear on Glass?

Tags: google-glass

I admit I am making the first steps with the glass demo app - I added a few items to the timeline and I was expecting them to appear immediately on glass. But it took quite a while, maybe a minute or so.

The app I have in mind needs to "push" data to Glass in a timely manner. Is this the normal behavior?

Answer (score 1):

A faster Internet connection will probably help.

The response time of the sync service, which synchronizes cards to your Glass device, will continue to improve over the course of the [Developer Preview](http://developers.google.com/glass/devprev). But, in general, it is designed for services that require response time on the order of several seconds.

If you envision a Glassware that requires real time updates, on the order of many per second, your project is probably a better match for the up and coming [GDK](http://techcrunch.com/2013/05/16/google-announces-native-glass-developer-kit-will-be-able-to-do-more-than-the-mirror-api/).

Comment: Hi, Can you provide some insight about sync service what is the underneath protocol used. Thanks

Comment: Not really. It's not part of the API and hence it's something we're constantly adjusting. If I said anything here it'd be obsolete before we knew it :)

Comment: Me and My friend are using same wifi, but the cards we push manually from our glassware comes in about 3 seconds to mine but my friend's comes in about 30 seconds...! Is this something to be with the glass hardware or is it bcs the number of glassware services we subscribed is causing the problem? In mine I have stopped all other subscriptions, my friends one is having the default subs.

Comment: If there are a lot of items continually coming down, it may slow things down a bit, but it should not cause a significant impact.  If you suspect something is up with your friend's Glass, I recommend they reach out to the Glass Guide team for support.

Comment: Actually we used 2 galaxy S3s earlier as emulator by installing apks got from the glass system dump. That problem must be bcs of many apps syncing.
Now we got our google glass at office, there is no problems in syncing
Thanks @JennyMurphy

Comment: Well there's your problem!  We don't test the Glass system software on any hardware other than Glass.